# How can I implement a drop down clickable icon menu using Twitter BootStrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am prettyn new in **Twitter BootStrap** and I have the following problem.

I know that BootStrap provide a **drop down** menu, something like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example

Implementing in this way:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see it show a **button** with **Dropdown** as text and when the button is clicked the menu voices are shown.

Now my problem is that i want something like this but I need to have a clickable icon, when the icon is clicked the drop down menu is shown (as is in FaceBook where clicking on the down arrow in the main menu you obtain a sub menu related to your profile).

How can I implement something like this using BootStrap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"
   style="background:url('https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png');background-size:cover;width:50px;height:50px">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You could do it like so... using css background and setting appropriate size

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"
    style="background:url('https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png');background-size:cover;width:50px;height:50px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this part

```
Dropdown
<span class="caret"></span>
```

to

```
<span class="glyphicon"></span>
```

and replace the word 'glyphicon' with the corresponding name of the icon you want to use from [Bootstrap's glyphicon library](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs)

eg.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
```

for a heart icon on your dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your code

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
```

to

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="http://www.futuregensoftwares.com/images/facebook_icon.gif"></a>
```

You can replace your img source with whichever icon you desire, add some additional style to make it awesome.
For Eg. I've used facebook's icon.